# Non-standard dc.js chart with crossfilter.js

Tags: javascript

I should build a dc.js chart with x-axis based on weeks and to colour the weeks (like a bar chart but with bars having fixed height) applying a rule on the type of facts that are within the week.

EXAMPLE:

dimension: weeks
facts gruped in 2 groups (new cars, used cars)
rule:

```
if (new cars sold in the current week >= 1) week color = green
  else if (used car sold in the current week >= 1) week color = yellow
  else color = red
```

the chart should appear as an horizontal bar (or week size aligned bars) having different colurs on the weeks depending by the result of the rule.

On the dc.js side I try to use a bar chart (but don't know how to fix the height)
On the crossfilters.js I do not find how collect the facts within a week for applying the rule.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if I use dimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {         return myFunction(d);});   i get only one item at a time and I cannot apply a rule on all the items placed in a specific week.

Comment: I would need a dimension.xxx() that gives me the array of items contained in the week